# PouchDB with Couchbase replication

Tags: couchbase, pouchdb, couchbase-sync-gateway

I'm trying to create an offline client application with [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) local document storage which will be syncing its data to a [couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/) server. I maintain three instances of couchbase to form a cluster. For the sync I want to use the [sync gateway](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/guides/sync-gateway/index.html) that couchbase provides

**Questions**

1. I will be running the *sync_gateway* on all instances of my cluster and I should be connecting to them in a round robin fashion? Is pouchdb capable of doing that, like adding more servers to replicate, and how?
2. I set up a pouchdb simple example and a couchbase and while pouchdb managed to replicate a document to couchbase I constantly get the following error, what does this means and how I can correct it:

   `GET http://localhost:4984/mybucket/_local/4jm_8Z70bAx9pah9QrJraw%3D%3D?&_nonce=1448874432705 404 (Not Found)
   explainError-browser.js:7 The above 404 is totally normal. PouchDB is just checking if a remote checkpoint exists.`

I connect with the following snippet of code

```
const localDB = new PouchDB('localdb');
const remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://localhost:4984/mybucket');

localDB.replicate.to(remoteDB, {
  live: true,
  retry: true
}).on('complete', function () {
  console.log('DONE');
  // yay, we're done!
}).on('error', function (err) {
  // boo, something went wrong!
});
```

Is there any good example, or a simple github repo example of how to perform a simple sync as a proof of concept between pouchdb and coucbase managing authentication and replication? So far I have been reading the following resources:

1. http://blog.couchbase.com/first-steps-with-pouchdb--sync-gateway-todomvc-todolite
2. http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/guides/sync-gateway/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This blog-post should give you the information you need, http://blog.couchbase.com/first-steps-with-pouchdb--sync-gateway-todomvc-todolite

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martin, I've followed the instructions of the over mentioned blog post from the beginning but the error i mention is still a problem, do u know what exactly means and how I can correct it? This error is not produced when I use couchdb